# Options from Graphics command

Tags: plotting, graphics

What do it mean $[[1]]$ in the following command?

```
Graphics[...][[1]]
```

How about the following command?

```
Graphics3D[...]/. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} :> {x, y, -10}
```

Comment: Take a look at `Part`, `ReplaceAll` and friends. And compare `Graphics[Disk[], PlotRange -> 5] // InputForm` with 
`Graphics[Disk[], PlotRange -> 5][[1]] // InputForm`.

Comment: What is meaning of $\{x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ\}$ ?

Comment: Try `tutorial/Introduction-Patterns` in documentation

Comment: What are your functional suggestions?